# Getting DestinationFiles refers to 1 item and sourcefiles refers to 1 item when publishing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, publish, publishing

Need help badly. I am **getting the below error** when publishing to folder.

[image]

With the below publish setting
[image]

[image]

The solution works perfectly fine when run. Only getting this error when publishing.

Please see below .csproj file
[image]

**Im so stuck. Don't know what I am missing.** I already tried to create new solution then publish it right away. Same error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, I need to relocate my solution to "(username)/source/repos" folder path. No need to downgrade or upgrade .Net framework. I stay using .Net 5. From there, I am able to publish my solution perfectly. No error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when i created a folder name that contains **'**.
When I removed the **'**, this got resolved.